# Finding multiple strings in text with regexp Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have the following string:

`background:url('http://images.bloomingdales.com/is/image/BLM/?&$b=BLM/swatches/&layer=0&size=322,23&src=is{$b$1/optimized/8757901_fpx.tif}&cropN=0,0,14,1&anchor=0,0&layer=1&size=23,23&src=is{$b$2/optimized/8757902_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.071,0&layer=2&size=23,23&src=is{$b$4/optimized/8234544_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.143,0&layer=3&size=23,23&src=is{$b$7/optimized/1111977_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.214,0&layer=4&size=23,23&src=is{$b$0/optimized/8538460_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.286,0&layer=5&size=23,23&src=is{$b$5/optimized/8234545_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.357,0&layer=6&size=23,23&src=is{$b$3/optimized/1111973_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.429,0&layer=7&size=23,23&src=is{$b$7/optimized/1252857_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.5,0&layer=8&size=23,23&src=is{$b$8/optimized/1252858_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.571,0&layer=9&size=23,23&src=is{$b$7/optimized/8234547_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.643,0&layer=10&size=23,23&src=is{$b$0/optimized/8757900_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.714,0&layer=11&size=23,23&src=is{$b$0/optimized/1111970_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.786,0&layer=12&size=23,23&src=is{$b$1/optimized/1111971_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.857,0&layer=13&size=23,23&src=is{$b$2/optimized/1111972_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.929,0&layer=14&op_sharpen=1&fmt=jpeg&qlt=90,0&hei=23')
    322px 0 transparent;`

I need to get all such parts :

`1/optimized/8757901_fpx.tif` , `2/optimized/8757902_fpx.tif`, etc..

I am using this regexp:

```
re.findall(re.compile(r'\d{1,2}/optimized/.+\.tif'), swatch)
```

Which returns a wrong result:

```
['1/optimized/8757901_fpx.tif}&cropN=0,0,14,1&anchor=0,0&layer=1&size=23,23&src=is{$b$2/optimized/8757902_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.071,0&layer=2&size=23,23&src=is{$b$4/optimized/8234544_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.143,0&layer=3&size=23,23&src=is{$b$7/optimized/1111977_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.214,0&layer=4&size=23,23&src=is{$b$0/optimized/8538460_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.286,0&layer=5&size=23,23&src=is{$b$5/optimized/8234545_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.357,0&layer=6&size=23,23&src=is{$b$3/optimized/1111973_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.429,0&layer=7&size=23,23&src=is{$b$7/optimized/1252857_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.5,0&layer=8&size=23,23&src=is{$b$8/optimized/1252858_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.571,0&layer=9&size=23,23&src=is{$b$7/optimized/8234547_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.643,0&layer=10&size=23,23&src=is{$b$0/optimized/8757900_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.714,0&layer=11&size=23,23&src=is{$b$0/optimized/1111970_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.786,0&layer=12&size=23,23&src=is{$b$1/optimized/1111971_fpx.tif}&anchor=0,0&posN=0.857,0&layer=13&size=23,23&src=is{$b$2/optimized/1111972_fpx.tif']
```

I have tested this regexp on regex101.com and there it works well:
https://regex101.com/r/tV9kU8/1#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re.findall(r'\d{1,2}/optimized/.+?\.tif', swatch)

                                            ^^
```

Make your `quanitifer` non greedy by appending `?` to it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of greedy `.+`, use the quantifier in ungreedy mode: `.+?`.
This way your regex will never match more characters between the `/` and `.tif` than needed, i.e. it will only match up to the next instance of `.tif`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [none greedy grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) in your regex (*Note that also in your pattern you need to put a `?` after `+` to make it [none greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)*):

```
>>> re.findall(re.compile(r'{\$b\$(.*?)}'), s)
['1/optimized/8757901_fpx.tif', '2/optimized/8757902_fpx.tif', 
'4/optimized/8234544_fpx.tif', '7/optimized/1111977_fpx.tif', 
'0/optimized/8538460_fpx.tif', '5/optimized/8234545_fpx.tif', 
'3/optimized/1111973_fpx.tif', '7/optimized/1252857_fpx.tif', 
'8/optimized/1252858_fpx.tif', '7/optimized/8234547_fpx.tif', 
'0/optimized/8757900_fpx.tif', '0/optimized/1111970_fpx.tif', 
'1/optimized/1111971_fpx.tif', '2/optimized/1111972_fpx.tif']
```

As all of you image path is after `\$b\$` you can use following pattern :

```
{\$b\$(.*?)}
```

that will match anything after `\$b\$` within `{}`.